# Initialize an Eigen::MatrixXd from a 2d std::vector

Tags: c++, eigen

This should hopefully be pretty simple but i cannot find a way to do it in the Eigen documentation.

Say i have a 2D vector, ie

`std::vector<std::vector<double> > data`

Assume it is filled with `10 x 4` data set.

How can I use this data to fill out an `Eigen::MatrixXd mat`.

The obvious way is to use a for loop like this:

```
#Pseudo code
Eigen::MatrixXd mat(10, 4);
for i : 1 -> 10
   mat(i, 0) = data[i][0];
   mat(i, 1) = data[i][1];
   ...
 end
```

But there should be a better way that is native to Eigen?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure thing. You can't do the entire matrix at once, because `vector<vector>` stores single rows in contiguous memory, but successive rows may not be contiguous. But you don't need to assign all elements of a row:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > data;
MatrixXd mat(10, 4);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  mat.row(i) = VectorXd::Map(&data[i][0],data[i].size());
```

Comment: Nice, so that reduces the problem by one, can you do a more complex map over the outside vector?

Comment: @Ben Not from a `<vector<vector>>`. You could if you had the matrix in a contiguous block of memory in row-major or col-major order.