# Map two-dimensional array to Eigen::Matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

I can't figure out if and how it's possible to map a two-dimensional double array to an Eigen::Matrix.
Is it possible to map an array `double d[][]` which I receive as `double** p` to an Eigen::Matrix?

While one-dimensinal arrays work fine, I wasn't able to map `p` to `Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, n, n>>`. Is that possible and how could it be done? The size `n` is not really constant, but I could accept a hard coded size.

---

I tried several versions, but none worked. I thought the following should work (assume the size `n` would be 4).

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>> p_OUTPUT(&p[0][0]);
```

The code compiles and runs, but only the elements of the first column and the first element of the second column map the correct values. Using `p[0]` as argument yields the same result.
Other versions I tried (for example without the `&`) did not compile.

Comment: Can you show what you tried and what you want to achieve? Is `n` a compile time constant? And are you sure `p` is a `double**`?

Comment: @AviGinsburg Thanks for your reply, I completed my question. The size `n` is not a constant, but a hard coded size would be OK. 
And yes, I'm quite sure `p` is a `double**` because `p[row][col] += ... ` works.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33669013/2899559) post.

Comment: @AviGinsburg Many thanks, I upvoted your answer at the linked post! I found a very similar solution just at this moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I found a solution. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839240/initialize-an-eigenmatrixxd-from-a-2d-stdvector/18839353#18839353) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668485/eigen-and-stdvector/33669013#33669013) the storage in not contiguous memory is the problem.

The following solution worked for me.

```
Eigen::MatrixXd ConvertToEigenMatrix(std::vector<std::vector<double>> data)
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd eMatrix(data.size(), data[0].size());
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
        eMatrix.row(i) = Eigen::VectorXd::Map(&data[i][0], data[0].size());
    return eMatrix;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer you gave yourself is kind of a clue: Eigen, by default, stores matrices in column-major format, meaning that elements from this matrix:

```
m(0,0)  m(0,1)  m(0,2)
m(1,0)  m(1,1)  m(1,2)
m(2,0)  m(2,1)  m(2,2)
```

Are stored in a big linear array as:

```
[m(0,0), m(1,0), m(2,0), m(0,1), m(1,1), m(2,1), m(0,2), m(1,2), m(2,2)]
```

Your data (judging from your answer) is in row-major format, which is why you're pulling out memory-contiguous rows from your array and assigning them into rows in your result. You can tell `Map` that your data is in `RowMajor` format, and it should read your data correctly:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4, Eigen::RowMajor>> p_OUTPUT(p);
```

Comment: No, you assume that `p` points to a contiguous section of memory. For a `double**` that is not guaranteed.

Comment: The original question says that it's a `double[][]` that is passed to the function as a `double**`; if it's declared as an array, then it will be contiguous in memory.